# Is this use of switchMap equivilent to assignment and subscribing?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been following this [Angular routing tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service) from Google. It includes a class which injects the `ActivatedRoute` as `route` and `HeroService` as `service`. It has the following `ngOnInit` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
      return this.service.getHeroes();
    })
  );
}
```

Whilst trying to understand exactly what is going on here, I've changed the `ngOnInit` method in the following way and the code still works as expected:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.heroes$ = this.service.getHeroes();

  this.route.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
    this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
  });
}
```

I find my code easier to understand as the two actions, populating `this.heroes$` and getting the id from the route, are distinct; the `switchMap` feels as though its overkill.

Is my `ngOnInit` equivalent to the original?

I've read that `switchMap` is returning a subscription to the first-order Observable and is also cancelling previous subscriptions. Is this something my code is not doing and is it something I should care/worry about?

I've also read that I do not need to unsubscribe `ActivatedRoute` observables. Is this the case, that I do not need to unsubscribe from the `paramMap` in my version of `ngOnInit`?

Comment: The first version guarantees the order of processing. The call to the service won't be made until the route param is returned. Your version runs the two subscriptions in parallel. So they aren't equivalent. Whether or not they are functionally equivalent depends on the relationship between `this.heroes$` and `this.selectedId`. If the service call were to depend on the route param, you would have to use the first approach.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse ...see blue box for confirmation on activatedroute not needing unsubscription

Comment: @KurtHamilton you’ve answered the question, why is it a comment?

Comment: @AndrewAllen I wasn't intending to write out a full answer, I just got carried away.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Thank you for pointing this out, I hadn’t even considered synchronicity of the results of the calls. Will the subscription cancelling feature of switchMap also be a relevant difference between the versions? I'm guessing as its called on onInit I wont get multiple subscriptions, but I don't know.

Comment: @Dom I couldn't just leave it like this! I've posted a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my original comment into an answer, with added thoughts...

**Original comment**

The first version guarantees the order of processing. The call to the service won't be made until the route param is returned.

Your version runs the two subscriptions in parallel. So they aren't equivalent. Whether or not they are functionally equivalent depends on the relationship between `this.heroes$` and `this.selectedId`.

If the service call were to depend on the route param, you would have to use the first approach.

**Update**

Reviewing this has led to think of a small but important difference. The first version is making duplicate service calls. The paramMap observable is going to fire every time the route param is updated. Below is one example of how this would happen.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    // this will be called every time the selectHero function is called
    this.selectedId = params.get('id');
  });

  this.heroes$ = this.service.getHeroes();
}

// Event handler, called from the HTML
selectHero(id: string): void {
  // Triggers emission of a new param value in route.paramMap
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: id }]);
}
```

If the call to the service were inside the param subscription, the service would get called each time. Assuming that the heroes do not change in the database for the lifetime of the component, and there is no app-side caching, then we are making redundant calls.

> I've read that switchMap is returning a subscription to the first-order Observable and is also cancelling previous subscriptions. Is this something my code is not doing and is it something I should care/worry about?

`switchMap` isn't unsubscribing the outer observable, it cancels the inner observable when a new value is emitted. I have created a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-template-tqy76j) to demo this.

Navigate to the "other" page and click one the "One", "Two", "Three" links. Each click will update a route param, and you will see a log which of the subscriptions are still running.

There is too much code to paste here, but it sets up the following supscriptions:

```
const p$ = this.route.paramMap;
p$.subscribe(params => {});
p$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(params => {});
p$.pipe(switchMap(params => of(params.get('id')))).subscribe(id => {});
p$.pipe(takeUntil(this.timerElapsed)).subscribe(params => {});
```

Subscriptions 1 and 3 will run for the lifetime of the component. This demonstrates that the presence of `switchMap` in your first example will not cause the subscription to self-unsubscribe, if that's what you were getting at.

> I've also read that I do not need to unsubscribe ActivatedRoute observables. Is this the case, that I do not need to unsubscribe from the paramMap in my version of ngOnInit?

There is precious little in the way of official documentation on this that I can find. It is an often repeated statement from reputable sources. [This](https://medium.com/@gesteira2046/goodbye-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-components-8817e1b21db2) relatively recent article re-states the claim.

> No need to unsubscribe from the activated route.

It is often stated that unsubscribing is generally good practice anyway, and if you use the `async` pipe (which I assume would be the case in your example), then tidying up subscriptions is automatically taken care of anyway.

**Conclusion**

1. Tidying up the observables

There is no difference between your examples. You do not need to tidy up `ActivatedRoute` subscriptions, and there would be no need to tidy up the service observable if it is from `HttpClient`.

2. Order of calls

Your first example guarantees the order, the second example does not. This is unlikely to have a practical impact, since the router would almost certainly return a param before the service returned a result (assuming an XHR request).

3. Number of service calls

Your first example makes 1 service call per param change (including the initial subscription). Your second example makes 1 service call for the lifetime of the component. Which one is correct depends on your caching strategy and data volatility.

I have revisited this because it is a more interesting question that I initially assumed. I'm glad I did, and I encourage you to slowly explore the powerful and perpelexing world of RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

The `switchMap` operator guarantees the order of processing. The call to the service won't be made until the route `param` is returned.

Without the `switchMap` the two subscriptions run in parallel.

If the service call were to depend on the route param, you would have to use the first approach.

Comment: This answer is a verbatim copy of Kurt Hamilton's comment.

Answer (score -1):

The first version leads to keeping `Observable` in `heroes` property, the second version - to an object, or an `Observable` object.

The first version guarantees an order of execution.
This line is executed first `this.selectedId = +params.get('id');`

In the second version you have to unsubscribe `paramMap`.